# XML DOMDocument PHP - Get node where attribute value

Tags: php, xml, xpath

**Purpose :**

Create a method to retrieve a nested element with a specific "id".

**What I have tried :**

- Retrieve the code with x path expressions via DOMXpath class query method. Every time an empty node list was returned
- - '/row[@id=' . $id . ']'
- - '//table/row[@id=' . $id . ']'
- - '/*/*[@id=' . $id . ']'
- Tried with DOMDocument::getElementById and i set the DOMDocument::$validateOnParse right after instantiating the DOMDocument class. This also returns an empty node list.

**Example XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table>
  <row id="1">
    <job>construction</job>
    <age>34</age>
    <name>bob</name>
  </row>
  <row id="2">
    <job>construction</job>
    <age>34</age>
    <name>bob</name>
  </row>
  <row id="3">
    <job>construction</job>
    <age>34</age>
    <name>bob</name>
  </row>
  <row id="4">
    <job>construction</job>
    <age>34</age>
    <name>bob</name>
  </row>
</table>
```

**Php code :**

```
Class SimpleORM{

    ...

    public function find($id)
    {
        settype($id, "int");
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($this->_dom);
        $expression = '/row[@id=' . $id . ']';
        return $xpath->query($expression);
    }

}
```

The fUll Php code can be read here -> https://github.com/Danoon/SimpleORM/blob/master/SimpleORM.php

**Question :**

Why is the proper element/node not returned and how can i achieve this?

**Calling the find function**

```
$users = new SimpleORM("users");
$result = $users->find(1);
```

Comment: Can you tell How you call this find function?

Comment: I have added it at the bottom within a codeblock.

Comment: A `__construct` that has `return` inside shows a wrong concept in mind. Also why do you post that many code here? Please *create* a code-example that shows your programming question and that is *as small as possible* while still demonstrating your issue.

Comment: @Dany Henriquez: And as you source Stackoverflow for your library on Github, I suggest you leave a link per each change you've taken code from so it's easier to track. And if you fix bugs later in that code, you can also fix the answer on stackoverflow then (or leave a comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    <?php
    $slideids = array();
    $get_id = 2; 
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->load('test.xml'); // path of your XML file ,make sure path is correct
    $xpd = new DOMXPath($xml);
    false&&$result_data = new DOMElement(); //this is for my IDE to have intellysense
    $result = $xpd->query("//row[@id=".$get_id."]/*");  // change the table naem here
    foreach($result as $result_data){
        $key = $result_data->nodeName;
        $values = $result_data->nodeValue;
        $slideids[$key] = $values;
    }

    echo '<pre/>';
    print_r($slideids);
?>
```

Sort of [reference Manual for XPath Queries/expressions](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html)

Comment: I ended up using an adaptation of this solution. So that is why i am marking this answer as the best one.

Comment: @Dany Henriquez: If you have got a different answer than this one, add it below as your answer as well. Only by that it's clearly visible what you originally asked about thus complementing the question.

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track but you made a mistake. The solution is indeed by far easiest if you use XPath:

```
'//row[@id="' . $id . '"]'
```

You forgot the " (double quotes) around the `id` attribute.

Comment: But when i replaced it with your xpath expression i still get an empty node list.

When i return $xpath->query($expression)->item(0)->nodeValue i do get the values.

So there is something wrong with my understanding of the methods i think.

Comment: silkfire has suggested the right way to execute XPath query. This should work in your case.

Comment: It seems to return an empty node list, but when id return $xpath->query($expression)->item(0)->nodeValue it does contain the right values concatenated as a string. This tells me i do not understand how the methods work.

Comment: @DanyHenriquez: How do you find out if the nodelist is empty or not?

Comment: @Silkfire: You should start to get credited for the source on github. Looks like it can't live without your code.

Comment: Haha why do you think so =)?

Comment: @hakre Use the `->length` property. If it's 0 then the node list is empty.

Comment: @silkfire: I know, however OP is not getting tired to say the list is empty and then demonstrates it is not. That's why I asked him how he can say the list is empty. Clarifying this will probably help him lern something :)

Comment: @Silkfire : That is the way i did it, But if someone is a newbie(like me) they may not know that.

Answer (score 2):

As you're using DOMDocument you will get object. So you need to fetch it like below.

```
$users = new SimpleORM("table.xml");
//print $users->_dom->saveXML();die;
$result = $users->find(1);
if($result->length)
{
    print $result->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

Note: I am getting proper result from above code.

**Suggestion:**

You can improve your function call for `find($id)`

Your current function gives all `three(job, age, name)` values together. But if you want to make it more flexible that you can pass an additional parameter in `find($id, $withChildren)`. Below is sample suggested code.

```
public function find($id, $withChildren=false)
{
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($this->_dom);
    if($withChildren)
    {
        $expression = '//table/row[@id=' . $id . ']/*';
    }
    else
        $expression = '//table/row[@id=' . $id . ']';

    return $xpath->query($expression);
}
```

and you can call it like where you can get all your result child elements in loop. By that you can also print `nodeName` with `nodeValue` which is better to look.

```
$users = new SimpleORM("table.xml");
$result = $users->find(1, true);

if($result->length)
{
    foreach ($result as $n){
        echo $n->nodeName." : ".$n->nodeValue."<br/>";
    }
}
```